@ng-idle/core: Timeout happening on one idle instance is causing the interrupt to stop working on the other idle instance
I'm using  "@ng-idle/core": "~11.1.0" and Angular 13 application.
I have two idle instances, one for auto logout and another one for screensaver.
If my screensaver is "Active" and if timeout happens on the first instance(i,e. autologout) and if I try to interrupt the screen then screensaver is not going off and its blocking the UI.(One thing is clear that interrupt subscription stops working in this scenario).
How to resolve this issue?.
Sample code for reference:
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES, Idle, LocalStorage, LocalStorageExpiry} from '@ng-idle/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'my-idle-app';
  private readonly screenSaver!: HTMLElement;
  private readonly screenSaverText!: Text;
  idleTime1: number = 1;
  private screenSaverIdle = new Idle(new LocalStorageExpiry(new LocalStorage()), this.ngZone);

  constructor(readonly ngZone: NgZone, private idle1: Idle) {
    this.screenSaver = document.createElement('div');
    this.screenSaver.id = 'screensaver';
    this.screenSaver.className = 'screen-saver';
    this.screenSaverText = document.createTextNode('---%');
    const movingTxt = document.createElement('span');
    movingTxt.appendChild(this.screenSaverText);
    this.screenSaver.appendChild(movingTxt);
    this.removeScreenSaver();

    this.screenSaverIdle.setIdleName('screenSaverIdleService');
    this.screenSaverIdle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    this.screenSaverIdle.setTimeout(false);
    this.screenSaverIdle.setIdle(10);
    this.screenSaverIdle.watch();

    this.screenSaverIdle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      document.body.appendChild(this.screenSaver);
    });

    this.screenSaverIdle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('IDLE END ::');
      this.removeScreenSaver();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idle1.setIdleName('AutoLogoutIdleService');
    this.idle1.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    this.idle1.setIdle(this.idleTime1);
    this.idle1.setTimeout(10);

    this.idle1.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("IDLE 1 STARTS")
    });

    this.idle1.onIdleEnd.subscribe({
      next: () => {
        console.log("IDLE 1 END");
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("idle 1 completed");
      }
    });

    this.idle1.onTimeout.subscribe(()=> {
      console.log("User session timed Out",);
    });

    this.idle1.watch();
  }

  private removeScreenSaver() {
    const ex = document.getElementById('screensaver');
    if (ex) {
      document.body.removeChild(ex);
    }
  }
}

I analyzed the source code of the ng-idle library and it seems like, since timeout value is "false"  for screensaver ideal instance it should not cancel the interrupt subscription.
So, my question will be regarding the instances of the services being created. Is it causing any problem here?.

could you share a simple stackblitz where the issue happens and steps to reproduce on the stackblitz

@NarenMurali - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-starter-project-qbltee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html

In this sample application. I have created two instances, idle1 instance for simulating the auto logout scenario and screenSaverIdle instance for simulating the screensaver scenario.
Auto Logout happens after 30 seconds (this.idle1.setTimeout(30)) and screensaver appears after a idle time of 10 seconds (this.screenSaverIdle.setIdle(10)).

The scenario where I'm facing a problem is :  After 10s the screen saver appears and if you interrupt before the timeout happens on autoLogout instance then it works fine. But if screensaver appears and If I interrupt after the autoLogout then screen saver doesn't go off and UI will be blocked.

I hope the answer is satisfactory?

It's difficult to pause/reset the timer of ng-idle2 looking at the source code. So I just stop and start the screensaver timer and this seems to work fine.
this.idle1.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('User session timed Out');
  this.removeScreenSaver();
  this.screenSaverIdle.stop();
  this.screenSaverIdle.watch();
});

Full Code:
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES,
  Idle,
  LocalStorage,
  LocalStorageExpiry,
} from '@ng-idle/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'my-idle-app';
  private readonly screenSaver!: HTMLElement;
  private readonly screenSaverText!: Text;
  idleTime1: number = 1;
  private screenSaverIdle = new Idle(
    new LocalStorageExpiry(new LocalStorage()),
    this.ngZone
  );

  constructor(readonly ngZone: NgZone, private idle1: Idle) {
    this.screenSaver = document.createElement('div');
    this.screenSaver.id = 'screensaver';
    this.screenSaver.className = 'screen-saver';
    this.screenSaverText = document.createTextNode('---%');
    const movingTxt = document.createElement('span');
    movingTxt.appendChild(this.screenSaverText);
    this.screenSaver.appendChild(movingTxt);
    this.removeScreenSaver();

    this.screenSaverIdle.setIdleName('screenSaverIdleService');
    this.screenSaverIdle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    this.screenSaverIdle.setTimeout(false);
    this.screenSaverIdle.setIdle(10);
    this.screenSaverIdle.watch();
    this.screenSaverIdle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(
        `Screen saver Active:: ${this.screenSaverIdle.getIdle()}::${this.screenSaverIdle.getTimeout()}::${this.screenSaverIdle.isIdling()}::${this.screenSaverIdle.isRunning()}`
      );
      document.body.appendChild(this.screenSaver);
    });

    this.screenSaverIdle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Screen saver Idle end ::');
      this.removeScreenSaver();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idle1.setIdleName('AutoLogoutIdleService');
    this.idle1.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    this.idle1.setIdle(this.idleTime1);
    this.idle1.setTimeout(30);

    this.idle1.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('IDLE 1 STARTS');
    });

    this.idle1.onIdleEnd.subscribe({
      next: () => {
        console.log('IDLE 1 END');
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('idle 1 completed');
      },
    });

    this.idle1.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('User session timed Out');
      this.removeScreenSaver();
      this.screenSaverIdle.stop();
      this.screenSaverIdle.watch();
    });

    this.idle1.watch();
  }

  private removeScreenSaver() {
    const ex = document.getElementById('screensaver');
    console.log(ex);
    if (ex) {
      document.body.removeChild(ex);
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
